# Assigning a pointer inside a struct in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Suppose I have a pointer `char *a`.

And

```
struct b {
unsigned short  num;
unsigned short  size;
unsigned char  *a;};
```

How should I assign stuff to 'a' in this case?
Thanks.

Comment: It depends what `struct b` on what is meant.

Answer (score 1):

declare variable of `struct b` type, then point `a` to existing memory location, or allocate memory for it using `malloc`

```
struct b buf;
buf.a = (unsigned char *)malloc(YOUR_SIZE_IN_BYTE);  // allocated memory for a
// fill content into a here
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Do you want `foo.a` to point to what `a` does? Then:

```
struct b foo = ...;
foo.a = a;
```

Or do you want `foo.a` to point to a copy of `a`? Then:

```
struct b foo = ...;
foo.a = malloc(sizeof(char) * lengthOfA);
memcpy(foo.a, a, lengthOfA);
```

where `lengthOfA` is `strlen(a)` if you have a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 0):

I have dynamically allocated memory and assigned to `pointer a`.

```
#define EXAMPLE_SIZE 25
main ()
{
struct b sample= { 0, };
sample.a = malloc ( EXAMPLE_SIZE * sizeof (unsigned char) );    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b obj;
unsigned char ch = 'F';
obj.a = &ch;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign in more than one way

1.Allocate memory dynamically (if you want user input)

```
// you can use realloc also if you want

struct b t1 ;

b.a = malloc(x * sizeof (char) );

//then you can read user from input.
```

2. While initialization can use a string literral

```
struct b t2 = {0,4,"hey"};
```